# when to set a table without primary key on a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, primary-key

Hey I am using the following tables. My table course_enrollments references the `user_id` and the `course_id`. Both columns combined are set unique.

`users`
`course_enrollments`
`courses`

Rails sets primary keys by default. I have read some articles of people who used these kind of join tables without any pk. e.g. by defining `:id => false`

Is it appropriate for this kind of join table? what about people enrolling or leaving courses or the search for enrollments. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally see `:id => false` on the migration for your join table when you want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, since Rails really doesn't like finding an `:id` primary key on these.

From the [`has_and_belongs_to_many` docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

> The join table should not have a
>   primary key or a model associated with
>   it.

Comment: Ah I see thx for your reply. But I dont use the has_and_belongs_to_many keyword, instead I use `has_many :courses, :through => :course_enrollments`. Isnt it the same? So should I delete my pk from my join table?

Comment: I guess it depends on your data model, but you should be fine leaving the ids in there. If you have a case where a user can sign up for the same class twice, then you'll need the ids, for example. Personally, I like to have the ids, and I also prefer to use has_many :through when possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Both columns combined are set unique

Therefore your table already has a key. Unless you require other attributes there is no obvious need to make another key for it.